# Why does $ find -delete not work sometimes?

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, find, manpages

I think what I'm talking about is this part of the manpage, which is *just barely* too indecipherable for me:

```
   -delete
      ... It will not attempt to delete a filename with a ``/'' character in its
      pathname relative to ``.'' for security reasons...
```

Specifically, what I'm trying to do is `$ find . -name '.svn' -type d -delete`.
I realize I can use `-exec` for this instead, but `find` appears to work without issue for other names, including deep in directories (that obviously contain many `/` characters in their pathnames).

Perhaps it's ignoring dotfiles instead and the documentation is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The "security reason" is that between the time that `find` is enumerating the files and deleting them, it may be possible for an attacker to modify one component of a file's path such that it becomes a symlink to an unexpected directory, resulting in your deleting a file of the same name from an unexpected directory. For example, you could end up deleting `/etc/passwd` rather than `/tmp/foo/passwd` if the attacker can change `foo` to be a symlink pointing to `/etc`.

Section 9.1.5 ("A more secure version of -exec") of the [GNU find documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html#Deleting-Files) discusses this problem in more detail.

Comment: It's the `relative to .` part that has me confused. I don't see why I can remove a file like asdf/somefile.txt using -delete relative to my working directory, but not asdf/.svn

Comment: The `.` is not talking about dot-files, like `.svn`; it's talking about the Unix notation for "current directory" or "working directory", which is `.`. In this context, I don't see a security reason to distinguish between dot-files and other files. So are you saying that your `find` command doesn't work on `.svn` but does work on other files? The only reason I can think of is `-delete` doesn't really work on non-empty directories, AFAIK.

Comment: Indeed--that's what's confusing about this. I understand that `.` is the working directory, but I don't understand how the manpage claims it is designed to fail on ALL subdirectories of the relative working directory, when that is clearly not the case.

Comment: Ah. Then it may very well be the case that the manpage is just out of date, and they have since implemented a more secure `-delete` and removed that limitation. I don't have access to any OS X machines, so I can't say for sure there.